# simpler expression for 1d differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system  of 1d differential equations, I want to know how the analytical solution looks like , I write the solution but I am not sure if it's right , I would be so happy if anyone can check it for me.

> $\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$For $1 \leqslant k \leqslant s$, $1 \leqslant n \leqslant s$,\begin{gather*}
> \frac{\d p_k(t)}{\d t} = -iω_k \cos(ωt) \sum_{n = 1}^s p_n(t) R_{nk}, \tag{15}\\
> \frac{\d}{\d t} \begin{pmatrix} p_1(t) \\ \vdots \end{pmatrix} = -iω_k \cos(ωt) \begin{pmatrix} R_{11} & \cdots & □ \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ □ & \cdots & R_{ss} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} p_1(t) \\ \vdots \end{pmatrix}.
> \end{gather*}
>   Diagonalizing $R_{nk}$ gives\begin{gather*}
> \begin{pmatrix} λ_1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots & λ_s \end{pmatrix},\\
> \frac{\d}{\d t} \begin{pmatrix} \tilde{p}_1 \\ \vdots \end{pmatrix} = -iω_k \cos(ωt) \begin{pmatrix} λ_1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots & λ_s \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \tilde{p}_1 \\ \vdots \end{pmatrix},\\
> \frac{\d \tilde{p}_k(t)}{\d t} = -iω_k \cos(ωt) λ_k \tilde{p}_k(t),\\
> \frac{\d \tilde{p}_k(t)}{\tilde{p}_k(t)} = -iω_k \cos(ωt) λ_k \,\d t,\\
> \tilde{p}_k(t) =\tilde{p}_k(0) \exp\left(-i\sin(ωt) \frac{λ_k ω_k}{ω}\right).
> \end{gather*}

Comment: My eyes are burning!

Comment: Could you provide a better image, take a screenshot or better still, take a photo of a printout?

Comment: This is not too much text in the photo to write out here

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: There is a sign error and you are missing the integration constants.